# What should be the input type for a neural network used for blood test?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have dataset of blood test with four columns . Blood groups are A+,B+,B-,O (string), antibodies values (numerical), age (numerical) and gender (string). I am feeding strings with categorical conversion (A+ = 00 , Male = 0) and numerical values as numbers for input.

As my neural network is trained I want it to predict any of the four values (blood group, antibodies amount, age , gender ). Below is the desired structure of my Neural Network.

1) Will my input for string types as categorical work ?

2) What to give as input if I want it to predict that value (for example I want it to predict 'antibodies' amount. Should I be giving it the following inputs (A+,50,M,?) = (0,0,50,0,?) ). What should I give as input for the missing value if its is numerical or string (for both type of inputs) ?

I thought of using 0 as input but that would give another mapping of relation with categorical inputs , am I right ?

[image]

Comment: You're questions are so hard to understand to me. Let me give it a shot making it clear for myself and possibly others. What do you mean by four columns for each sample? Does it mean that each sample has four separate columns relating to each blood type and all columns have the same interpretation except that the blood test is different?

Comment: If you had an image recognition problem, then it would be okay having zero values in the images, but try to avoid having zeros in your vectors as they may (specially if the number of zeros is large) lead to poor training of the model. So try to convert things like A+ to some numerical value (say 1)

Comment: Yes, it's hard to understand. My attempt: 1/ You have to provide data with the same type as the training you did. So if training was done with categorical strings or numeric values, you have to use that. 2/ I think it makes more sense to have one network per classifier. (1 for antibodies, 1 for gender, etc.). If your classifier depends on fields that are missing at run time, this is bad. And looking at your diagram, i see no reason why it would not.

Comment: Ok I try to make it more easy , I am using an autoencoder http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/images/thumb/f/f9/Autoencoder636.png/400px-Autoencoder636.png , It is learning to produce the same output as input to make a realtion between the inputs , I am confused that how to use it for test after training . What 4th input should I give if I have 3/4 inputs values and want to predict the 4th ?